# Computing trimmed mean along an axis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to calculate the trimmed mean along an axis, without explicit looping. So it
should do the same as:

```
arr=np.random.randn(3,10000)
arr[:,:5]+=999
arr=np.arange(3)[:,None]+arr
out=np.zeros(arr.shape[0])

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
   col=arr[i,:]
   m=np.abs(col-col.mean())<2*col.std()    
   out[i]=col[m].mean()

print out
print arr.mean(1)
```

Results in:

```
[-0.01085947  0.99187648  1.98009922]
[ 0.48822938  1.49126719  2.47951973]
```

Comment: I think you have some typos in your example.

Comment: Don't you want `<` in line 4 instead of `>`? I think you should test your function and post the expected input and output.

Comment: user: You where right. Added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> a = np.arange(24).reshape((6,4))
>>> mask=~(np.abs(a - a.mean(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]) < a.std(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis])
>>> mask
array([[ True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> ma.array(a,mask=mask).mean(axis=1).data
array([  1.5,   5.5,   9.5,  13.5,  17.5,  21.5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using masked arrays is the way to go here:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
arr = np.transpose(arr)
mask = np.abs(arr - arr.mean(0)) >= 2 * arr.std(0)
print ma.array(arr,mask=mask).mean(0)
```

Gives the same output as your code.